# Gitlab - problem with maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, gitlab, pipeline, maven-surefire-plugin

On gitlab, my request crashed and i got this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) on project todo-list: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /builds/java-learning-PL/todo-list/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
```

What could be causing this error? The tests work fine on my local machine.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.java.learning</groupId>
    <artifactId>todo-list</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>todo-list</name>
    <description>To-do list project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.spring.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I noticed that every mergue request which i push is end with failed because of above problem. Did you had the similiar problem and how can i fix this?
Regards

Comment: Can you share the pom?

Comment: sure, in the post below

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Ok i edit my question

Comment: See my comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093020/gitlab-ci-is-failing-due-to-maven-surefire-plugin-with-vm-crash/58653111#58653111 We fixed many issues like this one in 3.0.0-M4. And if you still have the same issue, ping me here or on GitHub and i will definitely have a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, when i used the maven:3-jdk-8 in my gitlab-ci.yml for the maven-build. 
I changed it to maven:3-jdk-9 and the issue was gone.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you Florian Kimmel, i fight with this for all day and i knew that is something wrong with no my project but maybe with Gitlab or some repositories, i add and deletes a few dependency but no one doesn't work. Thank you very much again :)

Comment: See my comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093020/gitlab-ci-is-failing-due-to-maven-surefire-plugin-with-vm-crash/58653111#58653111 We fixed many issues like this one in 3.0.0-M4. And if you still have the same issue, ping me here or on GitHub and i will definitely have a look!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're aware, but docker images change from time to time (details here https://hub.docker.com/r/library/maven/tags/). In your pom I can't see where is your surefire plugin specification but most likely you need to update the configuration

```
<configuration>
  <forkCount>0</forkCount>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Docker, Nix systems, and low version *2.21.0* of Surefire, it could be the problem with JDK 1.8 on Debian distributions or absolute paths in Booter JAR manifest.
Both issues have been already fixed in versions 3.0.0-M1 and 3.0.0-M2, but I would recommend you to use the latest version **3.0.0-M3** of Surefire. Setting *forkCount* to *0* is unrecommended since this is a workaround and may affect loading SPIs and system properties.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment in [GitLab CI is failing due to maven-surefire-plugin with VM crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093020/gitlab-ci-is-failing-due-to-maven-surefire-plugin-with-vm-crash/58653111#58653111)

**We fixed many issues like this one in 3.0.0-M4.**

If you still have the same issue, ping me here or on GitHub and i will definitely have a look!

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm running a test from TeamCity and getting the same error when using the Sikuli Screen class. When I run the test with Sikuli on the local machine, or from local to remote, everything works fine. When I run other tests without Sikuli from CI, everything also works. I am not using Docker, I am using Selenium Grid on a remote machine.

Comment: New version 3.0.0-M6 was deployed to Maven Central. Pls let us know your feedback. Enjoy!

Comment: The log report says that you should have a look in the surefire dump file and investigate the error in the dump, see the files in target/surefire-reports. I know that this is hard in Docker but it is important for the ASF developers that the dump file is reported in stackoverflow too.