# Maven tests fail with "forked VM terminated" in Docker

Tags: java, maven, docker, alpine-linux

While trying to build a Maven Java application within a Docker container, I encountered a strange error from the Surefire test runner plugin:

```
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /app && /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -jar /app/target/surefire/surefirebooter15847623166706412603.jar /app/target/surefire 2019-02-15T20-04-23_904-jvmRun1 surefire15681748693720284143tmp surefire_01815807763590795362tmp
```

The error is happening when using a JDK11 Docker image based on Alpine Linux ([adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jdk-11.0.2.9-alpine](https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11/)). It is consistently reproducing in this minimal Maven project: https://github.com/mxxk/mvn-surefire-plugin-failure.

After the failed test run, the only file in `target/surefire-reports` is: `2019-02-15T20-04-23_904.dumpstream`, and its contents are

```
# Created at 2019-02-15T20:04:24.258
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /app/target/surefire/surefirebooter15847623166706412603.jar
```

The next step would be to dig into this `surefirebooter*.jar` file and why it's considered corrupt, but alas it is only temporary and removed after the `mvn test` run.

---

Oddly enough, this Surefire test plugin failure only occurs:

- When using Surefire's mode of forking a new JVM (the default behavior); and
- On Docker image based on Alpine Linux. It does not reproduce on an image based on Ubuntu.

See https://github.com/mxxk/mvn-surefire-plugin-failure for more information.

---

## Update 1

This seems related to https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/issues/90. Per the advice in that issue, another workaround for this is to disable the system classloader in the Surefire plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This does indeed make the Surefire plugin issue go away. Nevertheless, it is only a workaround for whatever rootcause is behind it.

---

## Update 2

Switching the JDK11 Docker image from the aforementioned one to Azul Zulu OpenJDK ([azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11](https://hub.docker.com/r/azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine)) fixes the issue without any other workarounds. This is really interesting, since I used their image based on Alpine, so I would expect the same problem.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This is a bug on the maven docker image. I had created a similar error happening for jdk 8 on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093020/gitlab-ci-is-failing-due-to-maven-surefire-plugin-with-vm-crash/53226339#53226339. I think you won't find an answer to this question, may report the issue. If you want to workaround the problem I'd recommend you to change your docker image to another that works. If you are using an app based on jdk11, then play with different type of linux like `-slim`, `-alpine` or standard. If you use a lower jdk, then go for the same test using the lower jdk.

Comment: Thanks @FedericoPiazza, that's exactly right. I noticed that two alternative Docker images (one based on Ubuntu, another on Alpine) do not have this issue, so that's what I'm going with. I listed them in the README of [mxxk/mvn-surefire-plugin-failure](https://github.com/mxxk/mvn-surefire-plugin-failure).